# why is this undefined reference not being specified in the error message?

Tags: exception, lua

I have 2 pieces of fairly equivalent code, one generates an error message which specifies the erronous function call by name, but the other does not.  Why is this?

```
(f1 or f2)()
> stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value


if f1 then f1() else f2() end
> stdin:1: attempt to call global 'f2' (a nil value)
```

Comment: Because... it was too complicated for Lua to determine it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in Lua don't actually have names. Rather, when an error occurs, Lua will try to derive the name from the code. It works for simple static function or method calls (i.e. 99% of all calls), but not when you start treating functions more like values, as in your first example.

Comment: Yes! "Functions in Lua don't actually have names"

Answer (score 1):

What error message do you think would be better in the first case?

```
(f1 or f2)()
> stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value
```

In this code, the nil value comes from `f1 or f2`. The error message correctly reflects this. It does not mention any names because there is no name for `f1 or f2`.

Now, the nil in `f1 or f2` comes from *both* `f1` and `f2`. The error message *could* mention `f2`, but it'd be confusing.

If you write this, you'll get a better error message:

```
f = f1 or f2
f()
```